# What Dependency Does Go Use When The A Dependency Is Not Specified In "go.mod" file

Tags: go

I just inherited a Go project that has a go.mod file missing a declared dependency,  but the dependency is in the the go.sum file:

```
...

cloud.google.com/go/storage v?.?.? <- this is the missing entry in go.mod
...
```

these are the entries in go.sum file:

```
...
cloud.google.com/go/storage v1.0.0/go.mod h1:<some hash>
cloud.google.com/go/storage v1.5.0/go.mod h1:<some hash>
cloud.google.com/go/storage v1.6.0/go.mod h1:<some hash>
cloud.google.com/go/storage v1.8.0/go.mod h1:<some hash>
cloud.google.com/go/storage v1.10.0 h1:<some hash>
cloud.google.com/go/storage v1.10.0/go.mod h1:<some hash>

...
```

My questions are:

- Why are there 5 versions in the go.sum file?
- If there are other libraries that depend on these specific versions do all 5 get compiled into the binary?
- Which version of the lib will be linked to my application code since the dependency is not declared?

I tried to find an explanation in the Go documentation but could not locate,  any help appreciated.

Comment: If it is not in go.mod, it is not a dependency. Try running `go mod tidy`

Comment: If it's an indirect dependency, it's defined in a dependency's `go.mod`

Comment: go.sum is a kind of database recording hashsums of anything used anytime its contents does not determine which dependencies are used and in which versions. module will compiled into your binary at most once.

Comment: Thanks Volker, I think that answers my why are there five versions in the go.sum file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These dependencies are in all likelihood transitive dependencies, that is dependencies of the packages you depend on (or those that they depend on, etc). The go.sum contains lines for all dependencies of your module, direct or otherwise, in order for builds to be reproducible.

From [the Go blog](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules):

> In addition to go.mod, the go command maintains a file named go.sum containing the expected cryptographic hashes of the content of specific module versions
>
> ...
>
> The go command uses the go.sum file to ensure that future downloads of these modules retrieve the same bits as the first download, to ensure the modules your project depends on do not change unexpectedly, whether for malicious, accidental, or other reasons. Both go.mod and go.sum should be checked into version control.

The version of the package that does get included depends on the go.mod file of the package that you depend on. You may depend on several packages and each may depend on a different version of the dependency.

Whether they end up in your build depends on whether the dependency that includes them is compiled into your binary. An example where that inclusion may not happen are test files/packages, which will usually depend on testing libraries and their dependencies. These are never included in your average `go build` executable.

You can check the list of packages that will be included in your build like this:

```
go list -m all
```

You should just in case run `go mod tidy` to remove any dependencies that aren't actually needed anymore.

Comment: Thanks go list...  very useful,  basically listed that v1.10.0 would be included.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to mention since it appears relevant in this context that a situation such as described in your question might occur when using Golang's workspace functionality.

As mentioned in the [Go Blog](https://go.dev/blog/get-familiar-with-workspaces):

> With Go workspaces, you control all your dependencies using a go.work file in the root of your workspace directory. The go.work file has use and replace directives that override the individual go.mod files, so there is no need to edit each go.mod file individually

So this might result [in whatever way it does] in a module the go.mod file of which does not have a dependency used within its packages explicitly specified (dependency will not be mentioned in the go.mod file, but will be "import"ed in the files of the module)

Here's a picture of a directory structure I found in a [tangentially related issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/51106) which is nevertheless a good example of how implicit "require" is used by modules specified in a go.work file:

[image: An image of a tree of files in a folder where the go.work file, main folder, and "deps" folder are in its root. Note in go.work file: only the name of the folder containing the module is used. The name of the module specified in the go.mod file with the "module" keyword (e.g. module AmazingMod) inside of the specified directory is what determines what module this go.work file uses as reference whenever any of the modules specified inside of this go.work file refer to "AmazingMod"; note in main/go.mod file: no explicit "require" statement in this go.mod file; note in main/main.go file: despite there being no "require" statement in the go.mod file of this ".../main" module we can still refer to the ".../deps" module because the folder containing that module's go.mod file is specified to be used in the go.work file]